# Ошибка в WP class-wp-hook.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

на странице продукта появилось такая противная строка:

**Warning**: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'cusom_woo_info_1' not found or invalid function name in /home/din154/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line **286**

Как это исправить ?

Могу предоставить код.

Comment: Функцию с именем `cusom_woo_info_1` объявили? Она у вас в глобальной области видимости?

Comment: Объявил, спасибо, ошибка исчезла. Появилось вопрос: как теперь сделать отступ ID товара вправо или задать класс чтобы можно было на css отредактировать ? @Dantessss                                   https://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=3651a15360f36f4eda4568959b3a9e0f

Comment: Задайте отдельный вопрос.